# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+

Tags: android-studio-3.1

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:design:29.+.
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:design:29.+.
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:design:29.+.
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:design:29.+.
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
Open File
Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:design:29.+.
Open File
Show Details

Comment: Try looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56913611/how-to-fix-could-not-find-any-version-that-matches-com-android-supportappcomp). Hope this helps!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio keeps refusing to resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57022083/android-studio-keeps-refusing-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v729-0-1)