# How to fix " Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+

Tags: android-studio-3.1

how to fix

> `"Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
>   <a href="openFile:C:/Users/hhira/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApp/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.">Show Details</a> "`

Comment: Please post your code as a minimal reproducible example.
How do your build your project, what is your build file etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio keeps refusing to resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57022083/android-studio-keeps-refusing-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v729-0-1)