# How to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-appcompat

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.usman.testing"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: I have checked but does not resolve this issue

Comment: In any case [`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+'` **doesn't exist**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57022518/2016562).